# Youtube API key created by admin?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

Is it possible to generate a Youtube API key having admin access to the Youtube account? or is this function only possible for account owners?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can create a project on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)  You do not need to be an admin on anything to create an api key.

You should understand though that Api keys are used to access public data via the YouTube api.  This has nothing to do with a specific YouTube account.  It will just let you access the public methods like Video.Search

All methods that require authorization For example members.list  show in their documentation page that they require authorization.

[image]

The only authorization method allowed for the YouTube api is Oauth2.  Someone with access to the channel will need to authorize your application and grant consent that your application access their YouTube channel on their behalf.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to generate the API key, like you said anyone with access can create an API key :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#intro) does not state you can do it having admin access to the YouTube account only. But instead you need access to the actual Google Account linked to the Youtube Channel in question.

If you do have a Google Workspace subscription and the owner of the channel is one of your managed accounts, then you can access the GCP console and proceed with steps in the documentation to generate the key.